# iteratively and interactively writing and testing python code

Tags: python, pycharm

I'd like to iteratively write and test my python code in the Python console. I can't find a way to easily load what i've got written in the editor (somefile.py) into the Python console in Pycharm. Is there a trick to doing so?

Pycharm will let me run the entire script but that's not useful because i want to build up my state in the shell by experimenting with the functions and data i've got in the environment (kind of like how a lisp programmer would use a REPL).

Comment: you can run the script step-by-step in the debugger. between each step you can execute code, experiment.

Comment: @heck2mgl No. If I click Console it will show 'Connected to pydev debugger ...'. I can't actually use the console. That's not an answer.

Comment: Open a terminal and run the script like this: `python -m pdb script_name.py`

Comment: Again that's not what I'm looking for. The interactive environment building and testing is still lacking. What you just described is the same as just running the script with pycharms Shift+F10.

Comment: I'm using this since years, just wanted to help. sorry

Comment: Yes I understand, but we're all missing out on a useful feature. I can kind of simulate it using the pycharm debugger and using the 'Evaluate Expression' but that's not as good as having the console available for use while editing and modifying an already running a program.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm have this  [alt-shift-E  option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/loading-code-from-editor-into-console.html).

This way you can write in the editor, select the lines you want to run and run them by alt-shift-E.

I use it all the time, although I find a lot of people not fameliar with this option.

Comment: Alt+Shift+E is fine but it is basically copy pasting the selection. which means if you make a change to the function to retest you have to press up a few dozen times depending on the length of the function just interpreted. Really broken workflow wise.